# Excel - Conditional format on a column on new row entry, highlights row if 2 or more words matches the same 2 words in another row of same column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I enter account names for my company and I would like Excel to highlight somewhat "duplicates" of account names in past rows of the same column. Let's say row 200 is an account called "Green Yellow Orange Blue" and when i enter a new account "Green Red Yellow Black" in row 1500 for example under the account name column, i want it to highlight that row since two 2 words in that row match the same 2 words from the same column in row 200. What should my conditional formula be, assuming it ignores case sensitivity?

Comment: Do you have a “dictionary” (list) of all the words that can possibly appear?  (It’s easy to find lists of color names, but I assume that you are using colors only as an example.)  If you have such a list, this might be possible, but it seems difficult.  If you want to match any word that you might possibly ever type, then this may be very ***very*** difficult.  It might be manageable with VBA. … … … … … … … … Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?  Please describe what you’ve tried.

Comment: I imagine just creating a new column and entering a conditional formula on that. Essentially, highlight accounts that have been entered as a duplicate from another salesperson, but some accounts and applications go by different names (example Apple o/b Tim Cook and Tim Cook o/a Apple are the same company, just named differently)